# render a new comment form at the end of post#show

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

For a basic blog application (`Post` `has_many` `comments`) I want to display a new comment form at the end of `post#show`. But I'm stuck with the mechanics of building it and rendering the `web/templates/comment/form.html.eex` in `web/templates/user/show.html.eex`. The application:

```
mix phoenix.new my_app
cd my_app
mix ecto.create
mix phoenix.gen.html Post posts content:string
mix phoenix.gen.html Comment comments content:string \
post_id:references:posts
mix ecto.migrate
```

**web/models/post.ex**

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Post do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "posts" do
    field :content, :string
    has_many :comments, MyApp.Comment

    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w(content)
  @optional_fields ~w()

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end
end
```

**web/models/comment.ex**

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Comment do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "comments" do
    field :content, :string
    belongs_to :post, MyApp.Post

    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w(content post_id)
  @optional_fields ~w()

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end
end
```

In the `Post` controller I have the first problem. This code doesn't work (`key :post not found in: %{}` error):

**web/controllers/post_controller.ex**

```elixir
[...]
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  post = Repo.get!(Post, id)

  changeset =
    conn.assigns.post
    |> build_assoc(:comments)
    |> Comment.changeset()

  render(conn, "show.html", post: post, changeset: changeset)
end
[...]
```

The next problem is that I have no idea how to render the form. The following code doesn't work:

**web/templates/post/show.html.eex**

```html
<h2>Show post</h2>

<ul>
  <li>
    <strong>Content:</strong>
    <%= @post.content %>
  </li>
</ul>

<%= render "comment/form.html", changeset: @changeset,
                        action: comment_path(@conn, :create) %>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In `web/controllers/post_controller.ex`, replace `conn.assigns.post` with just `post` as that's the actual name of the variable.
2. To render a template from another view, (you want to render `web/templates/comment/form.html.eex` from `web/templates/post/show.html.eex`), you need to pass the view of the target template as the first argument:

   ```
   render MyApp.CommentView, "form.html", ...
   ```

   That's because the `render` in the controller is [`Phoenix.Controller.render/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#render/4) while the one available inside views and templates is [`Phoenix.View.render/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render/3) and they expect different parameters.